# Implement self-relations

Tags: doctrine, database-relations

Can anyone give me an example of how to implement a class self-relation?

Comment: More info on what exactly you want to do please.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
MenuOption:
  tableName: MenuOption
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      autoincrement: true
    child_menu_option_id:
      type: integer(4)
      null: true
    ... (more columns)
  relations:
    ChildMenuOptions:
      class: MenuOption
      foreignAlias: News
      foreign: id
      local: child_menu_option_id
```

You'd refer to your children like this once you've loaded a MenuOption object:

```
$menuOption = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from("MenuOption")
  ->where("stuff here")
  ->fetchOne();
$children = $menuOption->ChildMenuOptions; // this will be a Doctrine_Collection object
```